# A way to mimic the `tk busy` command with Tk 8.5?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Because my workbench tcl/tk version is 8.5, is there any alternative way to realize below function with tcl/tk 8.5 ? Thanks!

```
proc example {} {
    tk busy .top
    update 
    tk busy forget .top
    exec ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Never ever use `[update]`.

   If you think you should really use it, think again and don't ;-)
   See [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1255) for more info.
2. Merely post a popup window, then

   1. bring it to front — the [`[focus] command`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/focus.htm);
   2. make it "stay on top" — the [`[wm attributes -topmost]` command](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.htm).

   When you're done with the operation destroy or hide (withdraw) the window.

---

[This page](https://wiki.tcl.tk/3049) also explains how the BLT toolkit actually implements busy window, and gives further pointers.

Comment: Thanks very much! But I can't get the same clock-face result as "busy", when I add the .top configure -cursor watch.

Comment: @Jimmy: The cursor used depends on the platform. On Unix/X11 and OSX, it is `watch`. On Windows, it is `wait`.